# How to dynamically create a drop down entry using dojo

Tags: javascript, dojo

```
var DD =dojo.byId("xyz");
var optn = document.createElement("OPTION");
optn.text="text"
optn.value="val"
DD.options.add(optn);
```

What will be the dojo equivalend of above js code?

Comment: Didn't you ask this before? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5350525/how-do-dynamically-create-new-option-of-drop-down-box-using-dojo

Answer (score 2):

use fallowing code to create a drop down entry dynamically:

```
dojo.addOnLoad(function () {
    var select = dijit.byId("selBox");
    select.addOption([{ label: 'newValue1', value: 'nv1' }, { label: 'newValue2', value: 'nv2'}]);
    });
```

Full working example you can find [here](http://pastehtml.com/view/1dqai1q.html)